# Fastest way of comparing images from a video using java

Tags: java, search, optimization, quicktime

Ok so before asking I'm going to give a little background:
You are able to grab frames from a video using QuickTime java. My goal is to grab certain frames with a search method and compare the frames to see if they are similar. I know binary search is very efficient but what if you have like 1000 frames and the cost of grabbing a frame in terms of time every time you are going to compare two frames is very high.

My questions are:
Is there any approach faster than binary search for this problem with java?
Is there any way to decrease the cost of time?

Comment: Binary Search? It works on a sorted set. How do you sort frames?

Comment: I think you have to give us more information about what exactly you are doing. Probably also with some example images.

Comment: ok. So you have a video. You know they are in order of time. I extract a frame(image) from the video to compare it with another frame and use ocr to compare the text to know if they are similar for video segmentation. If the frames are similar then they are from the same segment(same subtopic of the video lecture). So the images contain power point presentation and a person giving the lecture.

Comment: @PrettyGirl I see. So you want to extract pictures of unique slides of a powerpoint presentation that was filmed together with the guy holding the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, what you are basically trying to do is find a vector of transition times (and by transistion I mean changing of the slide).

And you already seem to have some sort of mechanism to find out if two frames contain the same slide.

I would definitely go for some sort of binary search. You start with the first and last frame and always compare them to the frame in the middle between them (regarding time). If two frames are the same, you don't have to look between them (assuming the presentation is linear and does not have duplicate slides). You can also introduce a minimal duration of slides being shown (assume for instance that a slides is shown at least for 3s) which will provide an earlier break point for the recursion.

You could also assist the comparison by only provide them with the relevant part of the frame (detection of the beamer area).

Answer (score 0):

Binary search only works on sorted sets. So don't expect to find a lost frame in a "regular" video using that method.